# Requestid receiving as 0 for spring SOAP service

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, spring-boot-test

I developed one spring SOAP web service that is up and running. However, the request id I'm passing from the request is not getting updated. For all the requests I'm getting request id as 0. please help me with this issue.

My Endpoint details.

```
package com.example.thirdsoapweb.ThirdSoapWebService.soap;

import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.PayloadRoot;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.RequestPayload;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.ResponsePayload;

import com.in_28minutes.courses.CourseDetails;
import com.in_28minutes.courses.GetCourseDetailsRequest;
import com.in_28minutes.courses.GetCourseDetailsResponse;

@Endpoint
public class CourseDetailsEndpoint {
     //endpoint
    //reuestobject
    //respopnseobject
    //  http://in_28minutes.com/courses
    // GetCourseDetailsRequest
    @PayloadRoot(namespace = "http://in_28minutes.com/courses", localPart = "GetCourseDetailsRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public GetCourseDetailsResponse processCurseDetailsRequest(@RequestPayload GetCourseDetailsRequest request)
    {
        GetCourseDetailsResponse response=new GetCourseDetailsResponse();
        CourseDetails courseDetails=new CourseDetails();
        courseDetails.setId(request.getId());
        System.out.println(request.getId());// here only i'm getting 0
        courseDetails.setName("Rakesh");
        courseDetails.setDescription("Spring Microservices and for the first time");
        response.setCourseDetails(courseDetails);
        return response;
    }
}
```

**Request payload**

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <GetCourseDetailsRequest xmlns="http://in_28minutes.com/courses">
            <id>[908]</id>
        </GetCourseDetailsRequest>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

**Response payload**

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns2:GetCourseDetailsResponse xmlns:ns2="http://in_28minutes.com/courses">
            <ns2:CourseDetails>
                <ns2:id>0</ns2:id>
                <ns2:name>Rakesh</ns2:name>
                <ns2:description>Spring Microservices and for the first time</ns2:description>
            </ns2:CourseDetails>
        </ns2:GetCourseDetailsResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I tried debugging but cannot find out why I'm getting 0 in my request id. I want the requestid which I'm passing from the request.

Comment: Since this is about the mapping of the request to parameters to see the actual request would probably be helpful.

Comment: hi jens,  request:<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <GetCourseDetailsRequest xmlns="http://in_28minutes.com/courses">
            <id>[int]</id>
        </GetCourseDetailsRequest>
    </Body>
</Envelope>